# direction service failed due to

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <style>
      #map {
      height: 100%;
     }
     html,
     body {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }
   </style>
   <script>
     function initMap() {
        const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: { lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629 },
     });
     directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
     calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
   }
   function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
      const success = (position) => {
      var la = position.coords.latitude;
      var lo = position.coords.longitude;
      var latt = document.getElementById('latt').value;
      var lngg = document.getElementById('lngg').value;
      console.log(latt);
      console.log(lngg);
      directionsService.route({
         origin: { lat: la, lng: lo},
         destination: { lat: latt, lng: lngg },
         travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    })
     .then((response) => {
         directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
     })
      .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status));
    }
    const error = (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  }
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
 }
</script>
</head>
<body >
   <div id="map" ></div>
   <input type="hidden" id="latt" value="{{lat}}">
   <input type="hidden" id="lngg" value="{{lng}}">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API KEY HERE ] & c allback = initMap 
&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In destination when i give latitude and longitude then this code perfectly works but when i give latitude and logitude using variable then it shows error Directions request failed due to and cannot return any status i am using django framework for my project and fetching latitude and longitude from database.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I have never seen a Maps API error message that says "direction service failed due to". How hard is it to include the complete error message when asking a question?

Answer (score -1):

Need to convert latt and lngg to a number
example:

```
  var latt = document.getElementById('latt').value;
  var lngg = document.getElementById('lngg').value;
  var a = Number(latt);
  var b = Number(lngg);
  directionsService.route({
     origin: { lat: la, lng: lo},
     destination: { lat: a, lng: b },
     travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  })
```